# Android Push Notification Organizer

Tags: android, notifications, push

I want to develope an app that: 
1. gives the user controll on what push notification to display 
2. set the interval to display the notification

Do you know if such app requires root?

Thanks,
Maoz.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need Root to be able to do that 
Check this app wich turns off push notifs but need Root to make it possible https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff&hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this app.. I'm not talking about turning off the notifications,just not display them..

Comment: It's the same you still need root the app was only for example